# expected value with integration

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, probability-distributions

For the exponential distribution, $f(x)=(1/\theta) e^{-x/\theta}$ for $x>0,$ and $f(x)=0$ for $x \leq0$

$(i)$ Determine the exact value for the probability $P(0<X<3\theta).$

I need help with the integration. It has been a while since I have done this. Can anyone show me the working. Here is something that I did.

Here is what I did:

$E(X)=\int_0^{3\theta}xf(x)dx=1/\theta \int_0^{3\theta}xe^{-x/\theta}dx$

$u=x$ and $dv=e^{-x/\theta}dx$

$du=dx$ and $v=\int e^{-x/\theta}dx=-\theta e^{-x/\theta}$

$\int_0^{3\theta}xe^{-x/\theta}dx=uv |_0^{3\theta}-\int_0^{3\theta}vdu=(-\theta xe^{-x/\theta})|_0^{3\theta}+\theta \int_0^{3\theta}e^{x/\theta}dx$

Comment: That seems good to me.
(By the way, this kind of work can be verified by Wolfram Alpha.)

Comment: Isn't the problem asking for the probability and not the expected value?

Comment: We want $\int_0^{3\theta}\frac{1}{\theta}e^{-x/\theta}\,dx$. This is an easier integral than the one you tackled.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thanks. I got it. If you would like, you can write a solution and I will vote for it.

Comment: You are welcome. There is really nothing to add to the comment, I am sure you quickly got $1-e^{-3}$.